# Find the general formula for summation of square root of rational function

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

We were given a problem statement saying:
**Using discrete sum, find the area of the unbounded region limited by the curve $y^2=\frac{x(x-3)^2}{6-x} , x\ge3$ and its asymptote**.

I've made the following try: (sorry for the quality, I only have available my Mac's webcam): [Picture of the try](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/9434051combined.jpg)

But I get completely stuck when I get to the final summation as I have no idea how to come up with the general formula, I was thinking on how to put the summation in such a way it would be possible to solve with the telescoping rules, but I could make no progress at all.
I wonder if the whole idea to solve the problem is wrong.
Do you have some different ideas to solve this problem? Or can I somehow go on from where I got stuck?

---

I am adding this in response to the suggestions to put all my try here:
The graphic of the idea I am using is here: [Computer generated graphic](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9434125subir.png).

Initially we have the equation:
$$y^2=\frac{x(x-3)^2}{6-x}$$
As this is symmetric respect the $x$-axis it is enough to find twice the area below: $$y=\frac{\sqrt x(x-3)}{\sqrt{6-x}}$$ between $x=3$ and $x=6$, this second line is the asymptote.

So, to establish the Riemman sum we have: $a=3, b=6-\epsilon,$ where $\epsilon$ is the distance between the $x$-coordinate of the function and the asymptote ($x=6$). And now:$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{6-\epsilon-3}{n}=\frac{3-\epsilon}{n}$$and:$$x_i=a+i\Delta x=3+\frac{i(3-\epsilon)}{n}$$Finally we have the Riemman sum:$$\frac{A_n}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{3+\frac{i(3-\epsilon)}{n}}\left (3+\frac{i(3-\epsilon)}{n}-3\right)}{\sqrt{6-3-\frac{i(3-\epsilon)}{n}}}\frac{3-\epsilon}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3n+i(3-\epsilon)}{n}}}{\sqrt{\frac{3n-i(3-\epsilon)}{n}}}\frac{i(3-\epsilon)}{n}\frac{3-\epsilon}{n}$$$$\frac{A_n}{2}=\frac{(3-\epsilon)^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i\sqrt{\frac{3n+i(3-\epsilon)}{3n-i(3-\epsilon)}}$$Now, just for simplicity, let: $3-\epsilon=a$, and $3n=b$, then:$$\frac{A_n}{2}=\frac{a^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i\sqrt{\frac{a+bi}{a-bi}}$$ And well, (after my marathonic "typing"), here is where I get stuck as I couldn't make any more progress because of the overwhelming (for me) sum whose general formula is necessary to come up with. I hope your help, as it was very tiring for me to write all of this. :)

Comment: No offence but if you're not willing to have a clearer picture nor to type a summarised version of your attempt to a solution then why should anyone here be willing to help you? Help us help you by making it easier for us to read what you've tried to do. It's only fair, right? Keep in mind that people are busy and can't waste time trying to parse hard-to-read pictures. I know it sounds harsh but it really isn't when you stop to think about it.

Comment: discrete sum is meant to be the Riemann sum or any other discrete summation is acceptable?

Comment: I think any other discrete summation is acceptable, but I only found the Riemman sum as the most suitable (as I only know that kind of discrete summation).